# How to implement locking across a server farm?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, locking, scalability

Are there well-known best practices for synchronizing tasks across a server farm? For example if I have a forum based website running on a server farm, and there are two moderators trying to do some action which requires writing to multiple tables in the database, and the requests of those moderators are being handled by different servers in the server farm, how can one implement some locking functionality to ensure that they can't take that action on the same item at the same time?

So far, I'm thinking about using a table in the database to sync, e.g. check the id of the item in the table if doesn't exsit insert it and proceed, otherwise return. Also probably a shared cache could be used for this but I'm not using this at the moment.

Any other way?

By the way, I'm using MySQL as my database back-end.

Comment: There are multiple requests responses trying to access the database server at the same time.  That they are on a different server doesn't really change much.

Comment: OK, but they affect multiple records at the same time, I don't want another request affecting the same records while the first request still in action. In simple words, I want to have something like the lock keyword in C# but want it to work in a distributed way.

Answer (score 4):

Your question implies data level concurrency control -- in that case, use the RDBMS's concurrency control mechanisms.

That will not help you if later you wish to control application level actions which do not necessarily map one to one to a data entity (e.g. table record access).  The general solution there is a reverse-proxy server that understands application level semantics and serializes accordingly if necessary.  (That will negatively impact availability.)

It probably wouldn't hurt to read up on CAP theorem, as well!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate a distributed locking service such as [Zookeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/). It's a reimplementation of a Google service that provides very high speed distributed resource locking coordination for applications. I don't know how easy it would be to incorporate into a web app, though.

Answer (score 1):

If all the state is in the (central) database then the database transactions should take care of that for you.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_(database)

Comment: As far as I understand, transactions are used to ensure that all the statements in the transaction will be executed or none of them will. How is that related to locking or thread safety? Does the transaction lock all the affected tables (the tables involved in the transaction) or lock/block other transactions until it finishes?

Answer (score 1):

It may be irrelevant for you because the question is old, but it still may be useful for others so i'll post it anyway.

You can use a "SELECT FOR UPDATE" db query on a locking object, so you actually use the db for achieving the lock mechanism.

if you use ORM, you can also do that. for example, in nhibernate you can do:

```
session.Lock(Member, LockMode.Upgrade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a table of locks is a OK way to do it is simple and works.

You could also have the code as a Service on a Single Server, more of a SOA approach.

You could also use the the TimeStamp field with Transactions, if the timestamp has changed since you last got the data you can revert the transaction. So if someone gets in first they have priority.